# Highlighting nodes and its neighbors not working in sync with another opacity filter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a fully functioning d3.js force directed graph. There are various filters associated with the graph.

I am now trying to use the highlight feature i.e. if the node is double clicked then the node and all its neighbors are at a higher opacity as compared to the rest of the graph. And on double clicking again on any of the nodes, the entire graph will become visible.

This works just fine:

```
 var toggle = 0;
//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < d3GraphData.nodes.length; i++) {
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
d3GraphData.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});
//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}
function connectedNodes() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;

        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        //Reduce the op
        toggle = 1;
    } else {
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        toggle = 0;
    }
}
```

Now , I also have another opacity filter controlled through checkboxes. Unchecking of checkboxes makes the unchecked nodes invisible.

There are 4 node types:

```
 Agent,Customer,Phone,ID_Card
```

The nodes have an attribute

```
   d.visible:true
```

The current state of the **visible** attribute depending on what boxes are checked/unchecked stays maintained in the code for the opacity filter.

Below is the code for the section of checkboxes:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll(".node");
var lines = svg.selectAll(".link");

lines.style("opacity", function(d) {
  return getOpacity(d.source) && getOpacity(d.target) ? 1 : 0;
})
var nodeTypes = ["Agent", "Customer", "Phone", "ID_Card"];
var checkBoxes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < nodeTypes.length; i++) {
  checkBoxes.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[value="' + nodeTypes[i] + '"]')[0])
  checkBoxes[i].checked = true;
  checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    filterBy("type", checkBoxes[i].value, checkBoxes[i].checked);
  });
}

var toggleOpacity = function(attribute, value, visible) {
  circles.filter(function(d) { //filter circles by attribute value
            return d[attribute] == value;
          })
          .each(function(d) { //modify visible attribute
            d.visible = visible;
          })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { // get opacity
            return getOpacity(d);
          });
  lines.filter(function(d) { // get links for attribute-value
            return d.source[attribute] == value || d.target[attribute] == value;
          })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { // modify opacity
            return getOpacity(d.source) && getOpacity(d.target) ? 1 : 0;
          })
}

var filterBy = function(attribute, value, visible, highlightSelected) {

  if (highlightSelected) {
     circles.style("opacity", 0)
     lines.style("opacity", 0)

        toggleOpacity(attribute, value, visible)

    circles.filter(function(d){return d.visible;}).transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("opacity", 1);

    lines.filter(function(d){return d.source.visible && d.target.visible}).transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }
    else{
    toggleOpacity(attribute, value, visible)
  }

}
```

The highlighting of nodes right now does not seem to work when some checkboxes are unchecked.

For instance when **Customer** and **Phone** are checked, double clicking on the **Customer** node should only show the neighboring **Customer** and **Phone** node.

But even the other neighboring nodes, that were invisible tend to show up.

In the **connected nodes()** function, I tried to use the **visible** atribute of nodes.

```
 node.style("opacity", function (o) {
        return neighboring(d.visible, o.visible) | neighboring(o.visible, d.visible) ? 1 : 0.1;
    });
```

But this approach does not seem to work.

Since the  current state of **visible** attribute is already calcuated it is just a matter of using it right. But I am struggling to do that. Still my first project in d3.js , so appreciate the inputs.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfkcb5qb/26/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the desired behavior when other filters are active? E.g. When Customer alone is active (so other nodes are hidden) and you double-click a Customer, do you want to show the hidden neighbors?

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g0dm4q3n/1/
I have modified the `connectedNodes` function in order to adjust the opacity of the neighboring nodes when d is clicked and restoring their opacity according to the `visible` attribute - set by the other filters. This way, when there are only two check boxes checked, e.g. Customer and Phone, when you double click a node, it will highlight it with its neighbors (even if they were not visible due to the check boxes) and on double clicking it again it will return to it previous filtered state.

```
function connectedNodes() {
    d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
    // use d.clicked to save toggle
    if (!d.clicked) {
        //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
        d.clicked = true;
        node.style("opacity", function (o) {
            // if they are neighboring set opacity to 1 
            // else 0.1 and do not change visible attribute
            return neighboring(d, o) || neighboring(o, d) 
                                                    ? 1 
                                                    : 0.1;
        });
        // you might want to indicate the clicked node maybe with a different border

        link.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
    } else {
        d.clicked = !d.clicked;
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        node.style("opacity", function(o){
            return o.visible? 1 :  0;
        });
        link.style("opacity", function(o){
            return o.target.visible && o.source.visible? 1:0;
        });
    }
}
```

You might want to indicate that a node was double-clicked (take a look at this: http://eutravel.clmsuk.com/semantics/graph - it works on click. Also, give it some time to load because there's much data and many things going on there :) ) so that the user knows what to do.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: wow. thanks a ton. the main key was thinking in terms of the d.clicked event for a node. I just could not think in that direction.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) I find using the element itself to hold information about its state (visual-wise) very helpful in many situations. Your project is getting a nice shape btw!